# #hyperledger #caliper #node

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

[Hyperledger caliper error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PScI.png)

Hello All,

I am getting above error while trying to test node js chaincode with hyperledger caliper. I have changed language = node in config.json and made necessary changes to verb according to my chaincode. Could anyone please help?